# Where do I put database config values in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to connect to a different database than what is in my database config file.

I've been able to do this with the following in my model:

```
        $wp['hostname'] = "localhost";
        $wp['username'] = "root";
        $wp['password'] = "";
        $wp['database'] = "transfer";
        $wp['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
        $wp['dbprefix'] = "";
        $wp['pconnect'] = FALSE;
        $wp['db_debug'] = TRUE;
        $wp['cache_on'] = FALSE;
        $wp['cachedir'] = "";
        $wp['char_set'] = "utf8";
        $wp['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

        $wpDB = $this->load->database($wp, TRUE);
```

and then running queries like so: `$query = $wpDB->get();`

I can only get it to work when the config values are in the model itself (so there would be a lot of duplication). I've tried putting the config array in the constructor, but I get an error that it can't find it.

Where can I put the config array so I don't have to duplicate it and that's available throughout the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database configuration usually goes in `config/database.php`. You can configure multiple database connections and store them with different group names:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'host1';
$db['default']['username'] = 'user1';
$db['default']['password'] = '******';
$db['default']['database'] = 'my_db';

$db['other']['hostname'] = 'host2';
$db['other']['username'] = 'user2';
$db['other']['password'] = '******';
$db['other']['database'] = 'my_other_db;
```

The `$active_group` refers to the default group when the database class is loaded. To connect to another group in your model, you can use this in the model's `__construct` method:

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('other', TRUE);
```

While this doesn't play nicely with the more flexible `$this->load->model('model_name', 'alias', $config)` approach, it might be easier.

More info: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 2):

i think that [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/145901/#712942) can help you, directly from codeigniter forum :)

Comment: Links are OK in answers, but not by themselves. Please post the relevant information and use the link as reference.

Comment: @Madmartigan is right; your answer may be deleted if you don't [edit] and add some details.  For more info, please search on [meta] for what is and is not an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a config directory in Code Igniter where you can add your own config file:

```
system/application/config
```

In that same directory there is an `autoload.php` file where you can specify which additional config files you want to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the config file from the CodeIgniter.

To retrieve a config var, use:

```
$this->config->item('item name');
```

More info in the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since your config data appears to be database related, store them in

> system/application/config/database.php